# Что спросить у 1С разработчика перед его уходом из компании?

Tags: 1с

Из компании уходит единственный человек, который разрабатывал систему. А я только устроился и пока не очень разбираюсь в 1С.
Мне дали задание узнать у человека всё про 1С в компании и составить что-то вроде документации. А на мои вопросы, что значит "всё", ответить не могут.
Что следует у него узнать? Что может спросить следующий человек, который придет на его место, по проекту?
Пока только спросил про расположение баз данных на сервере. Что еще нужно спросить пока понять не могу.

Comment: Спросить можно о том, куда он уходит и есть ли там вакантные места =). Но в целом документация должна появляться ранее чем реализовывается проект.

Comment: @ipatev_nn, документация раньше проекта? Пф-ф. Это не модно.

Comment: Чем занимается компания? Продажи, производство, разработка, складские процессы и т.п.

Comment: @Sagittarius в основном инвестирование и продажи

Comment: Из вопроса не очень понятно, вы разработчик и вам это наследие придется поддерживать, или же просто надо собрать информацию, дабы передать следующему кро придет?

Comment: @Sagittarius да, нужно передать информацию следующему, мне поддерживать не нужно будет

Comment: Контакты у него спросите и за какие вознаграждения он будет готов вас консультировать после ухода.

Comment: @Kromster может есть какой-то другой вариант)

Comment: @ddsl31, товарищ **Kromster** правильно подметил. В полном объеме вы не соберете сведений. Тем более вы не знакомы с 1С. Да, какие-то вещи удастся аккумулировать, но по опыту скажу, у нового сотрудника, кому придется заниматься оставшимся наследием, будет немало вопросов. И зачастую они будут возникать в ходе работы, с течением времени.

Comment: О, эта грустная и печально частая история! Спросить стоит у руководства, осознают ли они, что годы опыта невозможно передать за две недели? А заодно узнать, выделялись ли ресурсы на документирование системы, почему не было дублирования критических важных для бизнеса кадров и почему не была организована постоянная передача знаний.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У систем на 1С, в том числе и полностью самописных есть своя специфика. Ниже постарался описать основные пункты, которые могут подойти к вопросу

> всё про 1С в компании

При этом часть вопросов может быть не актуальна, если у вас имеется администратор 1С, но к сожалению очень часто это один и тот же человек.

1. **Чем именно занимался человек?** Только разработкой, или ещё и администрированием системы (регламенты, предоставление/удаление доступов, разворот новых платформ и.т.д.). Описание задач которые выполнял.
2. **Общее описание системы** - система типовая, доработанная на базе типовой или полностью написана с нуля? Если типовая, либо сделана на базе типовой, то насколько отличается от стандартной.
3. **Наличие обновлений.** Актуально при использовании типовой или частично типовой системы. Для самописный не актуально, так как мы эти обновления и делаем. Но может быть момент, когда система была разработана внешним подрядчиком с нуля, и после внедрения мы её дорабатываем.
4. **Детальное описание системы** - какие модули есть, за какие бизнес процессы отвечают. **Очень важный пункт, если система самописная!** Интеграции с другими системами (выгрузки, загрузки, клиент банк). Регламентные задания, важные обработки. Карта прав и ролей (пример: бухгалтеру назначаем такие роли а кладовщику - такие).
5. **Архитектура 1С в компании** - где расположены клиенты (компьютеры пользователей, терминал), имеются ли сервера приложений и сколько, как настроена система лицензирования (программные либо аппаратные лицензии). Тестовые, продуктивные и архивные среды.
6. **Служебные учётки** - логины и пароли от них, для чего каждая предназначена. Логин и пароль от сайта ИТС (если есть).
7. **Бэкапирование** - как настроено и как работает. Кто отвечает. Выношу отдельным пунктом, так как здесь лучше перебдеть.
8. **Разработка** - открытые либо не завершенные задачи.
9. **Перечень проблем и сбоев за последний год** - здесь описываем по модели: что произошло, как решили, что сделали для профилактики. Частые и массовые объединяем, действительно серьёзные и сложные пытаемся расписать по отдельности.

Answer (score 5):

При уходе любого сотрудника из компании необходимо понимать что он вообще делал и зачем нужен был этот сотрудник.

- Самое первое - **разберите всю бизнес логику** прикладной области, в данном случае компании вашей. Поймите кто куда должен идти с запросом и когда и зачем и откуда получать ответ, так вы сразу поймете систему (хотя бы частично) и узнайте потом у уходящего сотрудника, что из этого автоматизированно.
- Если вы новый человек, вам стоит **разобраться что входило в основные его обязанности и как он их выполнял**. По ходу рассказа при любом непонятном моменте - накидывать встречный вопрос. Важно всё это записывать - тезисно на бумагу, параллельно на диктофон (человека стоит предупредить о записи :D)
- Узнать **что делать в нестандартных ситуациях**, какие "фичи" предусмотрены системой **и как их исправлять** - составить полный список "фич" с описанием и инструкцией по их починке.
- Если человек что-то разрабатывал попросите у него **как можно больше диаграмм того, как работает система**. Попросите диаграмму БД, со писком хранимок и описанием их работы (минимум по idef0 каждую функцию). Попросите UML диаграммы - классов, временные, любые бизнес процессы, которые он может описать - всё в диаграммы. Ну и конечно хоть какое-нибудь пояснение к диаграммам "на русском", это большая работа, но в идеале было бы хорошо описать каждую сущность, её поля, каждую функцию и т.п. в таком ключе, чтобы это понял любой человек (Это большая работа и может занять несколько месяцев, поэтому скорее всего нереализуемо в полной мере, а только частично, особенно если доки раньше не было. Вам, наверное, стоит изначально сосредоточиться на более глобальных вопросах).
- Важно узнать **все пароли и адреса от всего и полный список систем и инструментов, которые сейчас используются для работы**. Узнать какие инструменты и технологии необходимо знать новому сотруднику. Если есть возможность - пригласите старого сотрудника на интервью с новыми.
- Ну и само собой **контакты**, как написал [kromster](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177188/kromster) в комментариях

Успехов!

Comment: По пункту с диаграммами: не выглядит ли это как-то очень запарно для того человека? :) Насчет остального вопросов не возникло :)

Comment: @gil9red если тот человек,это уходящий, то конечно тут нужно постараться, но даже если он вспомнит треть всех возможных ситуаций,это лучше, чем ничего

Comment: Я похоже, неправильно посчитал и вопрос был про другой пункт, обновил комментарий :)

Comment: диаграммы бд, например, строятся автоматически, их останется немного объяснить. Какие-то диаграммы могут быть готовы, какие-то уходящий человек сам посчитает важным написать. В любом случае, я думаю, все согласятся, что даже 5 диаграмм с большой абстракцией, без деталей, лучше, чем 0. Я дополнил ответ тем, что с диаграммами и описанием важно не переборщить и стоит сосредоточиться изначально на глобальных вопросах. Спасибо!

Comment: Звучит логично :)